# iBooks is synchronising with iPad but not with iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, books

iBooks is synchronising with iPad (mini2) but not with iPhone (5s). All devices have the same settings and updated to the last OS although with iPhone synchronisation is going only in one direction: if I'm adding any book/pdf from iPhone in iBooks it's appearing in all devices. At the same time if I'm adding book from Mac or iPad in iBooks, iPhone cannot see it.
Has anyone faced such problem? Any tips how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked Settings > iTunes & AppStores > Automatic Downloads?

Comment: May seem like a dumb question but have you double-checked that you are syncing books with the iPhone in settings?